# How to remotely run a program with SSH independent of my current computer

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access

So I want to run a program from my Desktop, but I would like to have my Desktop "forget it", so that if my Desktop crashes or shuts down it won't affect the SSH program.

In other words: I want the task to be executed on the remote computer independent of the computer, with which I'm sending the task.

Why would I wanna do this? Because I'm executing a huge task on a huge computer (64 cores computer), which should take days to evaluate, but I don't want my current computer to have to wait for it. The last time my Desktop froze, and I lost all the progress I had.

I can imagine that this question has been answered a million times already, but I don't know what terminology I have to search for, and I don't know what this process is called.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `nohup` command.

Comment: @user000001 so after I login with ssh and go to the relevant directory, should I execute the program with something like "nohup ./myprog param1 param2 param3 > output.txt"?

Comment: Yes. And with `nohup ./myprog param1 ... > output.txt &` it will be executed in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Some methods

- Use `nohup`
- Use Screen

### Using Screen

Ubuntu : `sudo apt-get install screen`

```
 screen
```

then after you lost ssh session.

login to ssh again and then

```
screen -r
```

This will resume ssh session screen.

For more info `man screen`

Comment: `screen` is more useful for interactive computing than for batch processing.

Comment: Sure, but he stated he don't want to loose task progress if he gets kicked out of ssh session. In this case , screen is perfect candidate for job.

Comment: I understood "progress" as "execution of the computation", not as "partial output"

Answer (score 1):

You could use (on the remote big iron) the [batch(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_batch.htm) command since you want [batch processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing):

```
  local% ssh remotebigmachine
  remotebigmachine% batch << EOB
     ./myprog param1 param2 param3 > output.txt
  EOB
  remotebigmachine% exit
```

In the above both `local%` and `remotebigmachine%` are shell prompts (in practice they are something different).

BTW, for batch computation running many days, it is worthwhile to program some [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) (because even supercomputers may have power outages or hardware issues).